# Stripe::InvalidRequestError in CheckoutController#create

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-7

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am getting the following error,

You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or `line_items.images` in this API version. Please use `line_items.price` or `line_items.price_data`. Please see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices for more information.

for this code snippet.

[image]

I am trying to get a Stripe Checkout button up and running but kept running into this error

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe DID change their API so if your Stripe Webhooks is using the latest API which is "2022-11-15" then the code you have for line items was removed.

My app is using 2022-08-01 (looks like I also need to upgrade).
Here is a link to the breaking changes for API v2022-08-01 which is where those line items methods were changed/removed.
https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01

Here is a link that will take you to the new line items code you will want to use:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items-object